# How to create a plugin for Specflow Feature-level Templates

Tags: specflow

The idea of a "Feature Outline" has been a request for at least 10 years
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specflow/6bzgl9LYOFI

With many same or similar requests here in stackoverflow:

[Specflow Feature-level Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644835/specflow-feature-level-templates/22773085#22773085)

[Is there a Feature Outline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292636/is-there-a-feature-outline)

[Can i run a feature multiple times in SpecFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500608/can-i-run-a-feature-multiple-times-in-specflow)

[Specflow: maintain one Examples table for many Scenario Outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349847/specflow-maintain-one-examples-table-for-many-scenario-outlines?rq=1)

[Sharing a common set of Examples across multiple Scenario Outlines in Specflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120779/sharing-a-common-set-of-examples-across-multiple-scenario-outlines-in-specflow?rq=1)

[SpecFlow equivalent to parameterized test fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146845/specflow-equivalent-to-parameterized-test-fixture?rq=1)

[Using a background step like an Outline Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992647/using-a-background-step-like-an-outline-step)

There does not seem to be a solution for it.  I'd like to build such a plugin. How can I create a plugin for Specflow Feature-level Templates? (Can you provide some direction and/or samples?  What type of plugin  https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/wiki/Plugins , or is it multiple plugins?)

The requirement is to have SpecFlow execute the same feature file with different data/parameters.
The data can be defined as "Feature Examples", and those examples could be specified inline, or source it from an external file or database.  **For each line in the feature examples, execute the entire feature with the parameters from the one line.**

To paraphrase from the first link above: "   ... a "Feature Outline" would run all scenarios using a sequence of common parameters. Something like:

```
Feature Outline:

Background:
    Given I have opened the application using <browser>

# Scenario 1...
#  the scenario would reference the parameters of one/current feature examples row
# Scenario 2...

Feature Examples:
| browser      |
| firefox      |
| iexplore     |
| googlechrome |
```

Or, sourced externally, similar to how the Excel plugin specifies it:

```
@source:FeatureExamples.xlsx
Feature Examples:
| browser      |
```

However, my preference, it would be expressed more succinctly, and follow existing Gherkin language.  I.e. not introduce additional keywords, by just having a @source associated with the "Feature" keyword:

```
@source:FeatureExamples.xlsx
Feature: Calculator

Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered <a> into the calculator 
    And I have entered <b> into the calculator 
    When I press add
    Then the result should be <result> on the screen 
Examples:
    | case | a | b | result |
```

The Examples 'header row' would be allowed to specify just the columns needed by that scenario (even though the feature row data would have columns needed across all the scenarios). To support 'inline' examples, the @source could also look like:

```
@source: {
    | case     | a  | b  | result |
    | example1 | 10 | 20 | 30     |
    | example2 | 40 | 50 | 90     |
 }
```

(or csv, or JSON, etc. ;)

Comment: Asking for resources or samples is off topic for this site. You will need for fork SpecFlow, learn the code, the submit a pull request. I don't think they have any hooks for plugins.

Comment: @GregBurghardt  Off-topic? I respectfully disagree. I've read several posts about asking on-topic questions, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and I don't see any problem with my question.  I'm not asking for an 'off-site resource'; I've done some research and can't find anything relevant.  RE: " fork SpecFlow... [no] hooks for 
 plugins".   Yes, they have plugins.  I don't want to change the core code.  I've looked at 'sample plugins', e.g. SampleRuntimePlugin.cs  It's a one liner of little value. I think asking for some direction on how to solve the problem is a fair question.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a plugin which should help with your first example where you've used browsers.

The name of the plugin is `SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants` and documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/totaltest/SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants).

So if you specify

```
@Browser:Chrome
@Browser:Firefox
Feature: AnExampleFeature
```

Then each scenario will run for each of those browsers or 'variants' as I refer to them in this plugin. - Note that this plugin isn't secific for just browsers and the variants can be used for different needs.

However, this won't solve your issue of using examples with many parameters, for this I would agree that you would need a plugin specifically to handle this as you have mentioned.

I do think though that you would probably want a generator plugin rather than a runtime plugin. This is because if you look under the hood, scenario examples are used as part of the generation of the code behind (.cs) files.

You can have a look at the source code for my plugin, which is a generator plugin and see how I went about it.

I don't want to pre-empt how easy a solution for this would be without digging into it, but this does sound like some fundamental changes to SpecFlow would be needed. For example there are a few objects that would probably need updating to cater for feature examples - if you look at some of the files [here](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/tree/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Parser) you can imagine some of them would need adding to such as SpecFlowFeature.cs, possibly a new FeatureOutline.cs etc etc etc.

Comment: On Friday, I looked at three plugins including yours.  RE: "your first example where you've used browsers"... that was just to point out similar past requests.  My specific need is for features being run multiple times with different parameters.  I think rather than creating the new FeatureOutline, I will go with 'having a @source associated with the "Feature" keyword'.  I guess I don't really understand difference between generator and runtime.  If generator is right-clicking feature file for "generation of the code behind (.cs) files", then that does not seem to fit with what I want to do.